# Unable to open docker application from my host machine ( my windows machine) - localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: docker, localhost, containers, virtualbox, ip-address

My docker container is running successfully , but still I am unable to browse the application in my host machine . Without container I just tried to run in my windows  m/c , I can view the application in http://127.0.0.1:8000/  which is local host for me.
I tried 0.0.0.0:8000 portal
And also exposed port in docker file and ran docker by publishing using --publish option. I tried to access via bridge network assigned container. All the possible ways which were discussed in different forums were tried ..But in vain. Can someone help me on this. There could be two problems

1. docker virtual box not communicating with my host machine (but opened the portal by exposing and publish option)
2. May be I am referring to wrong ip address to view the application in my host m/c :
   But i checked ip address using docker inspect  commands and tried that as well
   docker network inspect -f '{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Subnet}}{{end}}' 329dd26d7270
   I tried with Mc Cafe firewall setting to  OFF :(
   The same problem exist while I was trying to browse my application (which is running in WSL) in my windows machine  without docker. Problem is my windows portal not accessing any type of virtual box either docker or WSL. I am suffering from this issue with big blockage to my next step towards my project.
   Hoping for the righteous solution

> ## Dockerfile
>
> ```
> # Pull base image
> FROM python:3.9
>
> # Set environment variables
> ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
> ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
>
> # Set work directory
>
> WORKDIR /code
> ADD . /code
> # Install dependencies
> # runs the pip install command for all packages listed in the requirements.txt file
> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
>
> # Copy project
> COPY . /code/
>
> EXPOSE 8000
> ```

Docker-compose.yml file shared below

```
version: '3.9'
services:
   web:
       build: .
       command: python manage.py runserver  
       ports:
           - 8000:8000
```

> $ docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS            PORTS                                       NAMES

```
24fe92f6c14c   hello_web   "python3"                16 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes                                                  hello-cc

e797bcd9629b   hello_web   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago       Up 3 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   hello-c1

83bc3424cf9d   postgres    "docker-entrypoint.sΓÇª"   2 days ago       Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   bee_project_db_1
```

**hello-c1 container not accessible with  172.27.112.1:8000 as well**

Got ip addresss for windows m/c using ipconfig

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::89c0:5e11:3776:9980%39

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.112.1

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile? is it hosting on 0.0.0.0? or its localhost? etc

Comment: Added those docker file information above. I tried to access my project in web browser, but in vain . So I executed a sample Hello world project to check where exactly the problem. My windows m/c host not communicating with docker container

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the docker toolbox under Windows, do

`docker-machine env` or `docker-machine ip`

You will find something like this:

```
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.103:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\fevly\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%i
```

You will  find your docker machine ip listed there as well. Take the IP and pair it with the mapped port you have just made it.

If you are using the docker toolboox under Windows then 127.0.0.1 does not belong to your docker. That 192.168.99.103 shown above is the IP of linux VM on which your Docker is running .., that is the default IP of that VM.

Comment: installed docker for windows which works inside the docker desktop where i can see my containers running and tried to use docker-machine in git bash and got surprised when no machines were listed but the docker itself was working

Comment: $ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

Comment: One more thing how to map ip address of docker machine with the specific container to my windows 10 server

Comment: Had obtained default gateway of my windows 10 server and tried to access  http://192.168.1.1:8000 , it saying error as 192.168.1.1 refused to connect. How to map this windows  gateway  of Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi  with my container. In my above question , i had updated with my docker file  and Ethernet adapter IP address as well. Pls do let me know how to map.

Comment: Had got an ipaddress from docker desktop tool under Network tab 192.168.65.0/28 as docker subnet. Do i need to map this to my local host. Because i browsed this address with 8000 port . No use. how can we map this default ip address of docker to my host machine. Normally in docker run command we give port expose and publish to open the port to external server. can u pls suggest the command to configure. since docker-machine ip doesn't give no ipaddress as it is asking docker machine name which doesn't exist while try to see 'ls' command. please do the needful

Comment: Look. You seem to be using 'Docker for Windows' rather than 'Docker toolbox', the difference is that the former uses native virtualization and doesn't require a virtualbox to run docker (docker-machine is specific to the later). But the underlying problems might be the same.

Comment: -If you’re using Docker under Windows then any port you publish with -p flag will be published on the VM’s (the linux VM not Virtual box) private IP address. Running docker inspect to find a container’s private IP address is just not really useful. Due to Windows host you cannot access the container with localhost directly due to something with a NAT network stack limitation - an old issue

Comment: -(explained  [here](https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/). Beside, you kinda defeat the purpose of Containerization (to isolate from underlying OS/machine)

Comment: Partial solution is to use the classic 'port forwarding' to expose it to outside the container (which I've did once within the Virtual box). Discussion for this particular issue is found [Issues 181](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/181), (the OP also encountered this under Windows server , seems to be fixed under new windows 10 released, I haven't read all the comments completely there though. I don't use Windows server but home so I couldn't really reproduce the problem over here.